# Multi threads ADC read and save on local file rpi pico

Tags: pi-pico, micropython, circuitpython

im trying to create a voice recorder using max9814 and raspberry pi pico with circuitpython/micropython and my problem is when it saves the recordings on .wav file some parts of the audio loses because the whole process is running on a core and I'm looking for a way to handle the recording and saving part on separated cores is there anyway to do that?

My code is below.

```py
import board
import analogio
import time
import adafruit_wave
import struct
import storage

# storage.remount("/", readonly=False)

adc = analogio.AnalogIn(board.A0)
conversion_factor = 3.3/4096
buffer = []

f = adafruit_wave.open("audio.wav", "w")
f.setnchannels(1)
f.setsampwidth(2)
f.setframerate(8000)

def save(data):
    global f
    f.writeframes(bytearray(data))
    print("done")

try:
    while True:
        sample = adc.value * conversion_factor
        frame = bytearray(struct.pack('>H', int(sample)))
        buffer.extend(frame)
        
        if len(buffer) > 16000:
            save(buffer)
            buffer = []
            print("clear buffer")
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print("closing")
    f.close()
```